# Bash script working but fails in crontab

Tags: bash, cron, rm

I am having issues with this script/cron. I am running on a Raspberry pi and I have other cronjobs working just fine(so I know its not cron on the system).

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /var/www/output/*
```

This script is working just fine in the command line 
`bash clearcsv.sh`
but when I try to turn it in to a cronjob, it seems that it is not executing

Cron script: `*/6 * * * * /home/pi/clearcsv.sh`

This should erase the contents of the "output" folder every 6 minutes, but it does not. If someone could tell me where I am failing or point me in the right direction that would be great

Thanks

```
total 160
drwxrwxrwx 14 pi   pi         4096 Mar 13 16:41 .

drwxr-xr-x  3 root root       4096 Dec 31  1969 ..

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi            0 Mar 10 21:56 ?

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi         8700 Mar 13 15:32 .bash_history

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi          220 Jan  7 16:10 .bash_logout

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi         3243 Jan  7 16:10 .bashrc

drwxrwxrwx  8 pi   pi         4096 Mar 10 19:24 .cache

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi           41 Mar 13 16:11 clearcsv.sh

drwxrwxrwx 12 pi   pi         4096 Feb 12 18:21 .config

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi          420 Mar 13 17:02 csv.sh

drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi         4096 Feb 12 18:20 Desktop

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi           35 Mar  7 08:17 .dmrc

drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi         4096 Jan 16 13:32 .fontconfig

drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   indiecity  4096 Jan 16 13:34 .gstreamer-0.10

drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi         4096 Jan 16 13:32 .gvfs

drwxrwxrwx  3 pi   pi         4096 Jan 16 13:33 indiecity

drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi         4096 Mar 13 13:27 input

drwxrwxrwx  3 pi   pi         4096 Jan 16 13:33 .local

drwxrwxrwx  9 pi   pi         4096 Jan 16 14:30 .Mathematica

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi         5781 Feb  3  2013 ocr_pi.png

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi            0 Mar 10 18:24 output.csv

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi          671 Mar 13 13:39 poller.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi          117 Feb 19 17:34 poll.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi          675 Jan  7 16:10 .profile


-rw-r--r--  1 root root          3 Jan 16 14:09 restart

drwx------  4 pi   pi         4096 Mar 13 13:22 .thumbnails

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi           56 Mar  7 08:17 .Xauthority

-rw-------  1 pi   pi        17227 Mar 13 16:56 .xsession-errors

-rwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi         2385 Mar  6 19:06 .xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -al /user/pi`?  My question would be in understanding if the user Cron is running as has access to that directory.

Comment: Have you allowed execution of the script? `chmod +x /user/pi/clearcsv.sh`

Comment: You are running `bash clearcsv.sh` from command line but `/user/pi/clearcsv.sh` from crontab, start by using the same in both.

Comment: @dtmilano I have ran both bash and crontab with and without the directory, bash works either way, the crontab does NOT work either way I try. I think your suggestion is a smart idea, and will be implementing it in all new code, any other ideas?

Comment: @bryceatnetwork23 I have update my question to include the output

Comment: @samsquanch I have allowed for execution, unfortunately it seems to make no difference, thank you though

Comment: @ChrisCharnegie Try scheduling your cron as `*/6 * * * * cd /home/pi && bash clearcsv.sh` and see if that works. Also, ensure that you  are not running the bash command with `sudo`, and that `/var/www/output/` and its content have `pi` as their owner.

Comment: @mu無 that command line `cd /home/pi && bash clearcsv.sh` worked! Thank you! However, it only works when I take out all of the windcards, `0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54 * * * * cd /home/pi && bash clearcsv.sh`  as well as  changing `rm -f /var/www/output/*`  to naming all files in the script. Any ideas why the wildcards are not working?

Comment: @ChrisCharnegie that's most probably happening because the folder `output` has a different user group than those of its files. can you check if that is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help. I have everything working now! Here is the code if you are interested

New Script used:

`#!/bin/bash
/bin/rm -f /var/www/output/*`

Cron
`*/6 * * * * cd /home/pi && bash clearcsv.sh`

Comment: Thanks Chris for sharing the solution! It makes sense in hindsight as the cron environment is different from the user environment that created the cron job... if you look at the .profile settings of your cron user, it will look different from your user profile.  Glad you figured it out.